# How to find 4 wheeler driver's location points in Android?

Tags: android

Is there a way in Android to somehow use the GPS to determine if the user is driving. I am trying to find location points within moving/parked car,like whether user is in diver seat or not?

Comment: Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first

Comment: asking someone to do some code for you is NOT how StackOverflow is intended to be used. Show your effort first.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way around but not sure its the best or not.
Any way you can track the user lat-lng using google location api and in your application you can start a alarm manager to keep tracking the current & last lat-lng if there is difference between user's current and last lat-lng then that means user is moving else not.
you can also try other algorithm to find out at which speed user is moving by differentiating the time interval between their current and last lat_lng.

Comment: Thanks Avinash. I know about finding car movement and speed. I was researching something very much similar to this https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/57549/how-to-prevent-users-using-your-app-while-driving.